# Setting inner html of a DIV after it is added to body tag

Tags: html, wordpress, event-handling, dom-events, elementor

I am working on a form widget on Elementor on WordPress, when the user submits the submit button of the form, it will show a pop-up which is created by elementor. The pop-up actually is a DIV tag including my HTML code which I wrote in an HTML widget into the pop-up, as below, and this DIV will be added by some Elementor function to the body tag of the page dynamically when user presses submit button.

```html
<div id="calenderchooser01" style="min-height:100px;"></div>

<script>
function calenderchooser(){
    var calenderhtml="";
    var numofunits = document.getElementById("form-field-field_numberunits");
    if(numofunits.value>=15){
        calenderhtml = "<div class='calendly-inline-widget'  style='min-width:320px;width:100%;height:650px;'>over 15</div>";
    }else if(numofunits.value<15){
        calenderhtml = "<div class='calendly-inline-widget'  style='min-width:320px;width:100%;height:650px;'>less than 15</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("calenderchooser01").innerHTML = calenderhtml;
    console.log(calenderhtml);
}
document.getElementById("thisisanidcustom").addEventListener("click", 
    calenderchooser
);
</script>
```

`thisisanidcustom` is the id of submit button form. Also, I tested it with assigning showing of this pop-up to a normal button.
In both cases when I press the button it shows error on the Chrome console:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
> ```

```
at HTMLAnchorElement.calenderchooser (9a48896437a750ba11b18d8323f96ea7.js:59)
```

it references this line :

```
document.getElementById("calenderchooser01").innerHTML = calenderhtml;
```

and I think it says that the `div#calenderchooser01` does not exist.
I think maybe the function call occurs before adding the DIV to the body tag. but I have not access to Elementor default functions to edit them and say after popup occurs call the `calenderchooser()`. so in this situation how can I call the function `calenderchooser()` right after popups shows up. I also thought of something like an event listener on DIV existing change state if available but found nothing.

Comment: `calenderhtml = "<div class='calendly-inline-widget' data-url='https://calendly.com/lisa-557/30min-1' style='min-width:320px;width:100%;height:650px;'></div>"`; this will not create an HTML element use 'document.createElement("DIV"); to create element

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me using window.setTimeout() method:

```html
<div id="over15" class='calendly-inline-widget'  style='min-width:320px;width:100%;height:650px;display:none'>over 15</div>
<div id="less15" class='calendly-inline-widget'  style='min-width:320px;width:100%;height:650px;display:none'>less than 15</div>

<script>
function functionCall(){
    setTimeout(calenderchooser, 100);
}
function calenderchooser(){
    
    var numofunits = document.getElementById("form-field-field_numberunits");
    if(numofunits.value>=15){
        document.getElementById("over15").style.display = "block";
        console.log("over15");
    }else if(numofunits.value<15){
         document.getElementById("less15").style.display = "block";  
         console.log("less15");
    }


}
document.getElementById("thisisanidcustom").addEventListener("click", functionCall
);
</script>
```